# sql query to get the persons with the same last name

Tags: mysql, sql

I dont know if its possible with SQL. I would like to write a query that show people with same last name meaning if two people with diffrent first names and same last name then should appear in my result is there a way to write this in a simple SQL query

```
example of my DB would look something like that: 
Fname   Lname
Syed    Abbas
Kim     Abolrous
Hazem   Abolrous
Sam     Abolrous
Herto   Acevedo
Gustavo Achong
Pilar   Ackerman
Aaron   Adams
Adam    Adams
Alex    Adams
Alexa   Adams

the desired result would be : 
Fname   Lname
Kim     Abolrous
Hazem   Abolrous
Sam     Abolrous
Aaron   Adams
Adam    Adams
Alex    Adams
Alexa   Adams
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT * FROM YOUR_TABLE WHERE Lname in (
    SELECT Lname FROM YOUR_TABLE GROUP BY Lname HAVING COUNT(Lname ) > 1
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You may try below query -

```
SELECT Fname, Lname
  FROM YOUR_TABLE T1
 WHERE EXISTS (SELECT NULL
                 FROM YOUR_TABLE T2
                WHERE T1.Lname = T2.Lname
                  AND T1.Fname <> T2.Fname)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Declare @t Table (FName varchar(20) ,  LName varchar(20))

insert into @t Values
('Syed'    ,'Abbas')
,('Kim'     ,'Abolrous')
,('Hazem'   ,'Abolrous')
,('Sam'     ,'Abolrous')
,('Herto'   ,'Acevedo')
,('Gustavo' ,'Achong')
,('Pilar'   ,'Ackerman')
,('Aaron'   ,'Adams')
,('Adam'    ,'Adams')
,('Alex'    ,'Adams')
,('Alexa'   ,'Adams')


select 
    * 
from @t 
where LName in (
            select LName 
            from @t 
            group by LName having count(LName) > 1
            )
```

Comment: I think this is SQL Server based answer. While OP needs Mysql specific answer.

Comment: @Ankit Bajapai, at this point mysql and sql have same syntax (i used table variable for example.)
https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-having.aspx

Answer (score 0):

This will work perfectly

```
SELECT * FROM your_table where Lname 
in (SELECT Lname FROM your_table GROUP BY Lname HAVING COUNT(Fname) > 1 )
ORDER BY Lname
```

Comment: It is not mandatory to write Lname just choose a column of the tuple and it will work

Answer (score 0):

That's simple

```
SELECT *
FROM users u1
WHERE exists(
      SELECT Lname
      FROM users u2
      WHERE u1.Lname = u2.Lname
      GROUP BY Lname
      HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
     SELECT DISTINCT 
            x.* 
       FROM my_table x
       JOIN my_table y
         ON y.lname = x.lname
        AND y.fname <> x.fname
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this code

```
SELECT Fname, Lname
FROM TABLE A
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT NULL
              FROM TABLE B
              WHERE A.Lname = B.Lname AND A.Fname <> B.Fname)
```

Comment: What is the difference between your code and Ankit Bajpai's code?